# Turning execvp() into a proper shell

Tags: android, linux, shell, fork, execvp

I'm working on an exploit in a smartphone's firmware update function. When rebooted into update mode, the phone will accept commands over USB and execute them as root (but with SELinux restrictions). This is quite handy, but it's a very limited shell, because the update program just passes the command to `execvp` (after forking), and doesn't hook up most of the file descriptors. So stderr is lost, anything interactive (like an actual shell) just hangs, etc.

I'm looking for a way to leverage this backdoor to provide a proper shell. So far, here's what I know:

- When you send a command over USB, the daemon forks, and the child then passes the command to `execvp`. I'm not sure the parsing exactly, but it looks like it just replaces each space in the command with a NULL byte to build the argument list. Redirection doesn't work; any characters like `>`, `|`, `&`, `;` appear to be just passed directly as arguments.
- The daemon runs as root, but SELinux prevents writing to most places, [re]mounting filesystems, etc. All writable areas are mounted as noexec, so it's not possible to push a binary and execute it, as far as I can tell.
- The process's stdout is sent back over USB, but its stderr and stdin are connected to /dev/null.
- There is a /bin/sh which is executable, but without stdin, it's impossible to execute anything in it.
- Having an actual shell probably wouldn't bypass any of these restrictions, but would be more convenient.

I suspect it might be possible to use some trickery with IFS or such to get /bin/sh to spawn a shell connected to the proper file descriptors so that it's actually usable, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. The limited shell executing the programs is likely duplicating `stdin` to `/dev/null` *before* calling one of the seven `exec()` functions, so whatever you do inside that new shell, you will never be able to feed it input. Have you tried `/bin/sh -c "command here"`? If the limited shell does indeed pass everything as an argument, this might be a workaround to get `sh` to execute some commands, but of course, it's not interactive.

Comment: I've tried that; it gets parsed as `/bin/sh` `-c` `"command` `here"`, so no good. I was thinking there'd be some way to re-connect stdin to the approrpriate `/proc/x/fd` of the parent process (where I can get `x` using `ps`). And especially having stderr redirected (even just to stdout) would be a huge help.